# Nesting included Twig templates?

Tags: symfony, twig

I'd like to pass the output of an included Twig template to another included Twig template as a parameter, like so:

```
{% include 'MyBundle:Default:tpl1.html.twig' with {'item': include 'MyBundle:Default:tpl2.html.twig'} %}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work as the syntax is invalid.
Any ideas how to nest templates like this / store the output of an included template in a variable?
Or is there an alternative way to accomplish what I want to do? I thought about defining blocks in the included template, but it does not seem to be possible to overwrite them from the "outer" template ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try settings the template's content in a variable:

```
{% set content %}
     {% include 'foo' %}
{% endset %}

{% include 'bar' with {'item': content } %}
```

It should work.